# Apache2 - Directory URL without trailing slash redirecting to different URL

Tags: php, apache, redirect, apache2

I'm having a problem auto loading index.php in subdirectories with Apache2.
This is what I see in browser console when connecting:

```
GET http://example.com/login                     HTTP 301 Moved Permanently
GET http://10.0.3.10/login/
Connection Timed Out
```

When I type in http://example.com/login/, it works as intended. Also, 
Root directory redirects to index.php properly.

I'm fairly new to this topic, would appriciate any help.

Default virtual host settings:

```
#NameVirtualHost *:80
<VirtualHost *:80>
        ServerAdmin webmaster@localhost
        ServerName example.com/
        ServerAlias www.example.com/

        DocumentRoot /var/www/example.com/
        <Directory />
                AllowOverride All
                DirectoryIndex index.php
        </Directory>
        <Directory /var/www/example.com/>
                Options Indexes FollowSymLinks MultiViews
                AllowOverride All
                Order allow,deny
                allow from all
        </Directory>
...
```

httpd.conf:

```
<IfModule dir_module>
DirectoryIndex index.php
</IfModule>
```

No .htaccess file used.

Answer (score 0):

I think your request is handled by a virtualhost with no ServerName, and at startup httpd probably warns you that it can't find a default hostname for your local IP (10.0.3.10)

Try removing the trailing slashes from your ServerName and ServerAlias. You will need to do even more if your ServerName or ServerAlias matches the systems hostname -- namely adding a dummy ServerName to your default vhost.

Comment: Actually I configured the virtual host in the default file, since I'm not planning on configuring an other website. Is this wrong?
I tried removing the trailing slashes, it did not help.

Comment: Using the default is fine, but those slashes are deffinitely wrong.  Are you going through a proxy that might change your Host header to that IP?

Comment: As far as I know, I'm not going through a proxy.